# Adding Fivestar rating each item in a view containing most recent stories?

Tags: views, 6, rating

I'm using the Fivestar module (drupal.org/project/fivestar) and was just wondering if it is possible to add it to a view of my most recent stories. Basically, I want it to appear below each item in the view so users can both view it and use it.

Comment: You need to add it as a relationship and then add it as a field. I can't remember the exact setup so I'll leave this as a comment rather than a full answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the Fivestar widget to your views is pretty simple:

1. Add the relationship *Node: Vote Results*
2. Add the field *Vote Results: Value*
3. Choose how you wish to display the widget by changing **Appearance:** to either *Fivestar Stars (clickable, with text)* or *Fivestar Stars (clickable, no text)*
4. Click "Update" and save your view

Comment: Wow thanks, that seems to work... however maybe I am doing something wrong because whereas I can get the Fivestar widget to appear and it is clickable, it seems to be a little erratic, and doesn't always respond to clicks... sometimes I get a message that just says 'saving your vote' when I try to click a star but it never actually does save, but I don't have that problem if I'm in the node rather than in the view...?

Comment: Not sure, could be an issue with the Views integration, but have not experienced that before